# jquery datatables click event from button

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. This was my first attempt at jquery.datatables and it worked fine. 
Now I am trying to add some more to it - like if a button is clicked (Refresh button in the code below), I want to refresh the grid. But the click event is not fired. Please help.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Home/JQDataTableEditableLayout.cshtml";
}

@section head{

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var oaddrTable;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        oaddrTable = $('#addrTable').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 300, -1], [50, 100, 300, "All"]],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/Home/AjaxIndexDataProvider',
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": "120%",
            "sScrollY": 500,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,

            "aoColumns": [
                                    { "sName": "AddressID", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "bVisible": false },
                                    { "sTitle": "Address Line 1", "sName": "AddressLine1", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true },
                                    { "sName": "AddressLine2", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true },
                                    { "sName": "City", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true,
                                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                                            return '<a href="http://www.google.com.au?city=' + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                                        }
                                    },
                                    { "sName": "PostalCode", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": true }
                         ]

        }).makeEditable({
            "sUpdateURL": "/Home/UpdateData"
        });


        $('#Refresh').on('click', function () { alert('aaaaaaaaaaa'); });


    });           //ready


        </script>
}

<button id="Refresh" type="button">Refresh</button>
<div id="demo"  style="width:1000px;">
    <h2>Ajax example</h2>


    <button id="btnAddNewRow" value="Ok">Add new address...</button> 
    <button id="btnDeleteRow" value="cancel">Delete selected address</button>
    <table id="addrTable" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>AddressID</th>
                <th>AddressLine1</th>
                <th>AddressLine2</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>PostalCode</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

regards n thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put it on JSFiddle? It's hard to search for errors without actually trying it.

Comment: ...sorry I have never used jsfiddle. Basically I am not getting the alert when I click on the Refresh button

Comment: On its own the event works. Try putting it before your datatable initialization.

Comment: Well, here you are with working code without your `dataTable` - http://jsfiddle.net/X7fdv/ You are using some non-standard library, so I can't test it. Put URL of your library into 'External Resources' and press `Update`. Then post resulting URL here.

Comment: Thanks David. btw I am not using anything special just standard jquery1.10.1.js, jquery.datatables.min.js, jquery.jeditable.js,
jquery-ui.js, jquery.dataTables.editable.js. ATM the libraries are included locally in my project. I will try to find appropriate urls and and update the jsfiddle.

Comment: The error went away after I added jquery-migrate-1.2.1.jas right after jquery-1.10.1.js. The alert box in the click event shows ok now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you aren't including the editable plug in.  So the call to DataTables works, but then you get a JavaScript error when you try to call makeEditable.  JavaScript stops and the `$('#Refresh').on(...` call is never made.  Try including the plug in, from here for example: http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js

Comment: Hi Bumptious,
Actually the page works perfectly fine, including the inline editing (jeditable) and italso updates the db via ajax.

Comment: Hi Bumptious,
Actually the page works perfectly fine, including the inline editing (jeditable) and italso updates the db via ajax. I noticed following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' jquery.dataTables.editable.js:126

Could it be causing the click event not to fire ?

Comment: The error went away after I added jquery-migrate-1.2.1.jas right after jquery-1.10.1.js.

The alert box in the click event shows ok now. 
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hmmm - maybe you need a newer version of DataTables? The .live method is deprecated in jQuery and maybe it was removed completely in 1.10.  Always post error messages if you can, it makes it easier to diagnose.  Consider using Firebug if you aren't already, it's an incredible debugger for JavaScript.

Comment: Yes it was completely removed from 1.10. Aactually the offending code was in the datatables.editables plugin. Their latest version 2.3.3 still has .live.